# Kue: best practice for continuously processing/polling the queue

Tags: node.js, kue

What is the best way to continuously process items added to the queue? I see the following method

```
queue.process
```

https://github.com/Automattic/kue#processing-jobs

but this will process and return. Items added after this call are obviously not processed.

I thought to do:

```
queue.on('job enqueue', function(id, type){
            queue.process('email', function (job, done) {
                console.log('processing one: ' + job.id);
                done(null);
            });
        });
```

But not sure if this fires multiple process methods ignoring the current queue status?

EDIT:

I have created a handler to listen to the 'email' type, yet it is only called once given the scenario below. Unless I am missing something, I would expect process to be run exactly 10 times here?

```
const queue = kue.createQueue();

        queue.process('email', function (job, done) {
            email(job.id, job.data, done);
        });

        var email = function(id, email, done) {
          console.log('job: %s, sent to: %s number: %s', id, email.to, email.number);
          done(null, {result: 'OK'});
        };

        queue
            .on('job enqueue', function (id, type) {
                console.log('job %s got queued of type %s with id %s', id, type);
            })
            .on('job complete', function (id, result) {
                console.log('job complete: ' + id);
            });

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            queue
                .create('email', {
                    title: 'welcome email for tj',
                    number: i,
                    to: 'tj@learnboost.com',
                    template: 'welcome-email'
                })
                .removeOnComplete(true)
                .save();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function passed to `queue.process` will get called for each enqueued job.

Think of it as an event handler: it "listens" for (in this case) *"email"* events/jobs, and for each one the handler function will be called. So it's incorrect that *"items added after this call are obviously not processed"*.

As per [the fine manual](https://github.com/Automattic/kue#processing-concurrency), *"by default a call to `queue.process()` will only accept one job at a time for processing"*, but you can increase the concurrency:

```
queue.process('email', 20, function(job, done){
  // ...
});
```

Some example code that shows the handler gets called for each new job:

```
const kue   = require('kue');
const queue = kue.createQueue();

queue.process('email', function(job, done){
  console.log('got job', job.data);
  done();
});

setInterval(() => {
  queue.create('email', {
    timestamp : new Date()
  }).save();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I am still seeing the "handler" only fire once for the edit above ^^

Comment: @Chev I can't reproduce; for me, the message _"job: XX, sent to: tj@learnboost.com number: YY"_ gets logged 10 times, as expected. Perhaps you should add some [error handling](https://github.com/Automattic/kue#error-handling) to make sure that there aren't any errors being thrown that may cause the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Was actually related to some issues with jobs in the queue it seems. The minute a cleared the queue out, it started working as expected. thanks again